# Where do I put this javascript code?

Tags: jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm using jQuery UI for the first time, and I'm going to create a datetimepicker control for a DOB field.

Here is how the view looks:

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<StronglyTypedHelpers.Models.Person>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#date').datepicker();
    </script>    
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <h2>Index</h2>

    <% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
        <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Fields</legend>

            <div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name) %>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name) %>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name) %>
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Age) %>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Age) %>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Age) %>
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.DOB) %>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DOB, String.Format("{0:g}", Model.DOB)) %>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DOB) %>
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Married) %>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%: Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Married) %>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Married) %>
            </div>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Save" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>

    <% } %>

    <div>
        <%: Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index") %>
    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

Now the UI documentation says to use this code:

```
$('#date').datepicker();
```

Where do I put that?

Here is the link to what I'm reading:

http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/getting-started/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cant put javascript in your title. you must put it in your content

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
       $('#date').datepicker();
    });
</script>

    <h2>Index</h2>
  ...
```

the document.ready is like the old javascript windows.onload, only, the document.ready fires more early, and doesnt wait for images to be loaded :)

Comment: This worked. Thanks! Also, why do I need to use the .ready() function?

Comment: you want your datepicker code to be executed on an event. for example a button click, or here, the page load. remember the $(document).ready(function () { ... }); code, because almost all jQuery code starts within this 'code' this code simply tells the script. when the page (document) is loaded, (but skip the slow loading images etc, just the HTML) so when the HTML of the page is loaded, execute this function. then the code within this function is executed like your datepicker. this is how you do jQuery :) you'll love it soon enough ;) load of examples on jQuery website.

Answer (score 0):

This should work... just put this anywhere you have HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$({
// put jquery code in here
});
</script>
```

yeah, the problem is that you don't have a jquery declaration... thats why you do `$({ })`

you can also do this which is the more universal way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        // jquery in here
});
</script>
```

this you should be able to put anywhere, but its probably best in the head bit of your html.

Comment: The script doesn't get executed, but instead is set at the Title of my web page. I need to somehow tell MVC2 to not render it but treat it as code. Using the <% tags aren't working either.

Answer (score 0):

You can put it at the end of the document, like this:

```
.
.
.
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#date').datepicker();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Or, if you have the jquery.js and jquery-ui.js called in the head of the page, just add

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#date').datepicker();
});
</script>
```

just before the `</body>` tag